Aliens sent to prepare Earth invasion, camouflaged as toy makers. Mission goes wrong because female Martian falls in love with tax agent
I need to remember a short story in a science fiction magazine (old publications maybe between 1937 and 1965). The story is about extraterrestrials (must be Martians if I remember) who were sent in advance to Earth to prepare a future invasion. They infiltrated a toy maker shop and came to live there. One of them had a woman body camouflage. They were discovered by a government tax employee (a man) who found something weird in their tax report. I don't remember how the story ended but something did go wrong as the alien living in woman body started having emotional attraction for the government tax agent.

Welcome to the site. Nice question! Please add in more details if you remember them. The oddest little details can often be really helpful.

Sound so much like a Philip K. Dick idea but I don't remember that as one of his stories.
